# SWFLoader and loading events

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I'm using an SWFLoader that I declared like this:

```
<s:SWFLoader id="widget" maxWidth="150" maxHeight="75" maintainAspectRatio="true" />
```

And I also have a method to set its source from a ByteArray:

```
public function set widgetSource(widgetSource:ByteArray):void
{
    this.widget.source = widgetSource;
}
```

It works fine but it seems like setting widget.source is done asynchronously and I need to know when it finishes loading the data...I tried several things without success, including adding a Event.COMPLETE listener to 'widget' but the event is never fired. Any ideas?

Comment: either way you will need an event to listen and check its progress..

Comment: Yes, but which event to listen? On which element (widget, widget.loaderContext, widget.loaderInfo, widget.content.loaderInfo...)? I tried several things but none worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the event listener to the loader itself, For example

```
   var url:String = "yourlocation of file";
   var myWidgetLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   myWidgetLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
   myWidgetLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));

   function completeHandler(event:Event):void
   {
     trace(" fully loaded ");
   }
```

Also you can add a progress event to check the progress of the loader, let us know how you go.